# How to set URL for new organization in Liferay through coding

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I have to create organization in liferay through code right now I am using

```
liferayOrganizationService.addOrganization(parentOrganizationId, organizationName, OrganizationConstants.TYPE_REGULAR_ORGANIZATION, false, 0, 0,ListTypeConstants.ORGANIZATION_STATUS_DEFAULT, organizationName, true, serviceContext);
```

But through this I am not able to set the friendlyUrl for the organization as it is getting created automatically. So is there any way in which I can customize the organization URL. Please, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The friendly URLs are associated with the sites that you create along with an organization. You can use [GroupLocalService.getOrganizationGroup](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/GroupLocalServiceUtil.html#getOrganizationGroup%28long,%20long%29) to get the group associated with this Organization, then continue to operate on this. Group is the technical name for site.